# RSS examinations

Tags: self-study

Are the RSS examinations worth doing as a way to learn more statistics? I have been working a physicist for most of my life so I'm a little bit loathed to pay to learn maths as I can usually get my head around new statistical methods as and when I need them. The problem I have is that I only use what I know about and on more than one occasion after lurking on sites like this I have found myself thinking 'Oh, if only I'd have known that back then'. The RSS course seems like a way to force myself to learn and only have to pay for the examinations.

Comment: I'm looking into the RSS examinations myself, specifically the 5 exams needed for the Graduate Diploma. What's a bit off putting is the fact that the study books suggestions are pretty broad. Do you have any experience with the exams to share a year and a half after you've asked this question? Thanks.

Comment: I have decided they are a good idea and have been doing some some of the studying but my progress is limited I'm waiting to see if work will pay :p. So I'm a little loathed to do too much until I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with other routes such as an MSc in statistics, the RSS exams have two benefits:

1. Self discipline: you have to learn to pass the exams, including things which, without the incentive of an exam, you might personally feel are not interesting enough or are too difficult to pursue
2. Demonstration: having a formal qualification demonstrates to others that you have a particular level of knowledge that it might be difficult to show by other means

But as ever there are costs, and it is likely that you will learn things that you never subsequently apply.